# Golang lib/pq postgresql create a dynamic update statement

Tags: json, postgresql, go, sql-update

I get a JSON from a client on the successful submit of user details.

Some element in the JSON can be skipped since they were not updated.

On the Golang server side, I have an equivalent struct defined.

The server successfully marshals the JSON bytes into the struct.

```
type user struct {
    Id       *int64  `json:",omitempty"`
    Name     *string `json:",omitempty"`
    Age      *int64  `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

How do I create a dynamic update statement depending on the available JSON elements?

For example, I might get the Id and Age alone.
How can I create a update statement dynamically, like `update user set age = $1 where id = $2`
Another time it might be Id and Name.

Comment: So id can be empty? Seems strange to me; how would you know what to update.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to use an ORM, try a SQL generator like [Squirrel](https://github.com/lann/squirrel), and check every argument before modifying the sql statement:

```
import (
    sq "github.com/lann/squirrel"
    "fmt"
)

statement := sq.Update("user").Where(sq.Eq{"Id": &u.Id})
if &u.Name != nil {
    statement = statement.Set("Name", "Jack")
}
sql, args, err := statement.ToSql()
fmt.Println(sql)
```

In some scenarios you may need to query the DB first to make sure the input data is not trying to explicitly set column ´Name´ to null (like `update user set Name = null` ...).

A different approach will be to use an 'ORM-ish' package like [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp) or [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm), both should handle sql updates properly.